# XML validation expects an element that is optional

Tags: .net, xml, validation

I have a .NET client using WCF. For validation, I use an xsd like:

```
<xs:complexType name="MyBaseType">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="Family" type="FamilyType"/>
        <xs:element name="Relatives" type="RelativesType" minOccurs="0"/>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

When I try to send an XML instance that contains only the "Family" but with no "Relatives" element, the validation results with:

(Translated):

> The content of element "myBase" in namespace "..." is incomplete.
>   Expected a list of possible elements: 'Family, Relatives' in namespace
>   "..."

(Original):

> "Der Inhalt des Elements "myBase" in Namespace '...' ist
>   unvollständig. Erwartet wurde die Liste der möglichen Elemente:
>   'Family, Relatives' in Namespace '...' "

But the "Relatives" element is optional (does not need to be present) according to the schema, as it is specified with `minOccurs="0"`.

Is there anything I've missed in the Reference.cs? - just apart from some *System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute* I had to add to the autogenerated code.

Used tool: svcutil, 4.0.30319.1

Comment: Just as an experiment, what happens if you make the `Family` (the first) element in your sequence `minOccurs="0"`?  Or what if you put a "dummy" element at the end of your sequence?  I'm not sure how this might help specifically, but perhaps it might shed some light on exactly what circumstances cause the problem, which might in turn help you research the problem by googling on more specific symptoms.

Comment: Also might help to show the command-line switches you're using with svcutil.

Comment: Also, worth trying out nillable="true" for Relatives.

Comment: There is no question about changing the xsd. It is a given fact. - As you might guess I only extracted an example part stuff. I already tried the 'IsNullable = true' way.=> no effect.

Comment: I have the same problem (same error msg) with VS2017, .NET 4.6.1, though I use my own XMLSchemaValidator. Does someone know a Xerces validation tool (like svcutil), to get a little bit more info where and why  .net xml schema validation dies?

Comment: **Correction:** the validator was right - I have missed a mandatory element burried in the inheritance tree. But the **validator exception msg is missleading** and that was the problem..